# How to create accessory views in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am using the Netbeans platform for a little project.   Have a few questions...   How do you create docked accessory views?   Are all views TopComponents that have individual docking properties?   How do you create a view to the left of the TopComponents that shows a hierarchy of data in a tree control?   I have looked at the Window manager and TopComponents but nothing googles for Accessory view.    I would like to create a master-detail application...   I would like to create views that are automagically docked for the master relationship and use Topcomponents/Scenes for the detail views.   Any words on how to do this?

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about `modes`. TopComponents are docked into modes.

NetBeans platform by default provides few modes like `explorer`, etc. NetBeans platform also allows you to define your own modes so you can dock your TopComponents at different places.

To create new modes see official documentation provided in the `Windows System API`.

[See here.](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/doc-files/api.html)